# Matchstick Squares

Tags: matches

Twenty-four matchsticks are used to create a **3 x 3** grid. Can you remove *eight matchsticks* from the configuration so that you are left with two squares that do not touch each other?[image]

Comment: Don't just edit questions to keep them active.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Hi, I edited my post not to keep it active but because I wanted to get the badge for 'First Edit'. I didn't know it wouldn't work and that you have to edit someone else's post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The squares needn't be of the same size.
>
>  So, keep all the matches forming the border, keep all the matches forming the center-most square, and remove the 8 matches that join the small center square to the large outer square.
>
>   In the below illustration, remove the 8 red matches, leaving behind a blue and green square that don't touch, as they're nested: 
>
>  [image]

Comment: Sorry, but can you be a bit more clearer what you want to say?

Comment: Added an image to help illustrate it, @KhushrajRathod

Comment: Oops, I was too slow :-) Took me ages to get the formatting right.

Comment: "Remove the 8 matches which do not contribute to the outside square or the central square"

Comment: Yep, that's a cleaner explanation :-)  @theonetruepath

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the following $3\times3$ square:

```
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
|  |  |  |
 -- -- --
```

remove 8 matches to leave the following two disjoint squares (removed matches denoted by dots):

> `-- -- --`
> `|  .  .  |`
>   `. -- .` 
> `|  |  |  |`
>   `. -- .` 
> `|  .  .  |`
>  `-- -- --`

Comment: Correct Answer, But You were a bit late :P